# Assigning values to years and quarters in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, concatenation, assign

I need to assign values to years and quarters in SQL. I have two variables: `Development_Year` and `Development_Quarter`. `Development Year` values are years, and `Development_Quarter` can be values "1,2,3,4". As of right now, these two are separate fields in the table. Eventually, I want to create an actuarial triangle where the column fields are like the following: 1998Q1, 1998Q2,....,1999Q3, etc. To do this I need to concatenate them, but I'm unsure how.

Then, I want to assign a temporary value to a year and month starting from a year, say 1950, to current. The end goal is out of those new values, select every 3, and then return the original value the temporary value stood in for, concatenated with the quarter number.

I haven't tried any code, but I'm thinking about possibly making the values something similar to this (with the quarter value being concatenated on?): `(actual year-starting year) * 12 + Quarter`.

I'm sure this is very confusing - let me know what I can clarify.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. This question doesn't make much sense as posted. There just isn't anywhere near enough information for this to be clear. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for how to ask a question and then [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to get an idea of the kinds of details you should provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand, You can knock this out with a recursive CTE to generate all the years, then cross apply the result set with possible quarters, then concat:

```
DECLARE @quartervals TABLE (Quarterval VARCHAR(2))
INSERT INTO @quartervals
VALUES
('Q1'),
('Q2'),
('Q3'),
('Q4')

;WITH cte AS (
--get 60 years of ints:
SELECT 1950 AS year_
UNION ALL 
SELECT year_ + 1 
FROM cte 
WHERE year_ < 2010
)

SELECT CAST(cte.year_ AS VARCHAR(4)) + qv.quarterval AS year_quarter

FROM cte
CROSS APPLY @quartervals qv
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with the variables that are already in my table? (The `development_year` and `development_quarter`)

Comment: @d_and_a_kate Its tough to know what you are looking for without tables and data. Update your post to include tables with data and show the exact expected output.

Comment: Honestly, I think your code is probably the way to go! I don't think I know what I'm looking for either lol. Your code did produce the results I eventually want - so I'll go with that! Thanks.